# Creating a parallel arithmetic operator in an infinite loop in C compiler on Mac Terminal

Tags: shell, command-line, scripting, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void main (void)
{
        while(1) // infinite loop
        {
                int a, b;
                printf("Give me an integer a: ");
                scanf("%d",&a);
                printf("Give me an integer b: ");
                scanf("%d",&b);
                        sum = &a + &b;
                        product = &a * &b;
                        difference = &a - &b;
                        echo Here is your sum, product, and difference:
                        printf("Sum: %d + d% = %d.\n", a, b, sum);
                        printf("Product: %d * d% = %d.\n", a, b, product);
                        printf("Difference: %d - d% = %d.\n", a, b, difference);
                return 0;
        }
}
```

I keep getting a syntax error with my void main (void) on line 6
Using child processes to create 3 parallel processes.

Answer (score 2):

This program has a bunch of problems, and it's not doing anything in parallel:

```
void main (void)
```

This will usually compile, but according to the C standard it's not correct. The signature of `main()` that takes no arguments should be `int main(void)`.

```
sum = &a + &b;
product = &a * &b;
difference = &a - &b;
```

You're using the *addresses* of `a` and `b` instead of the *values*, so you'd always get the same results for `sum`, `product`, and `difference` (except that didn't define the last three.) The correct version should be:

```
sum = a + b;
product = a * b;
difference = a - b;
```

```
echo Here is your sum, product, and difference:
```

This isn't a C construct, so the compiler will complain about this. Use `printf()`.

```
return 0;
```

Although you've indicated that the loop should be infinite, it won't be because you exit the function at the end of the loop.